# Russian Meteor Explosion

Tags: rain

Yo Russian Guys !

Someone recorded the sound of Russian Meteor Explosion ?

Answer (score 4):

ian headley has a pretty great composite going on.

https://soundcloud.com/ianbattenfieldheadley/fs-11-meteor-russia-feb-15

Answer (score 1):

One should have set up a recorder with half an hour pre-rec all the time ...

... meteors ... earthquakes ... imagine: aliens! ...

no one would be prepared to record them ... it's a shame!

Comment: lets start a kickstarter!! Permanent awesome SFX recording project!

Answer (score 1):

fascinating!! Like, the boom and the glass blowing, its the type of thing you have to imagine the SFX, we're been graced with the chance to hear it (albeit from mobile phones)

BTW, if a sonic boom can blow out a window, what would it do to a mic?

Comment: I don't know the exact math/physics, but I think a sonic boom resonates bigger surfaces more heavily than smaller ones, otherwise everyone would also be deaf after this explosion.. luckily that's not the case, too many victims already (1000+)

Answer (score 1):

NASA should do that in the future. Stick a contact mic to an asteroid and await SFX heaven!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the exact same thing, but I guess no one would have had the time to setup a rig that fast.. You'd need dynamic mic's and a really good preamp to record that pressure wave. Judging by the videos on youtube the pressurewave was gigantic (and very loud).

Comment: Yes it's too loud.Maybe a portable recorder and after declipper.Maybe....

Answer (score 0):

It happened at early morning, so there is a minimal chance that someone were recording at that time.

Comment: I think am9:00 not too early :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting contact mics on asteroids is the sort of thing Id expect of Tim Prebble...

Answer (score 0):

I bet that was a really intense experience. It's really sad that so many people got injured though.

Answer (score 0):

here you go

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlX7xO6rWts